# Logic behind choosing the exponent bias as $2^7 -1$ instead of $2^7$ in $32$ bits IEEE-754 floating point representation

Tags: floating-point

The $\text{IEEE-754}$ uses $32$ bits to represent single precision floating point numbers. The partitions of the register are as follows:

```
        Biased
 sign  Exponent  Mantissa
+-----+--------+---------+
|1 bit| 8 bits | 23 bits |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

Now in general $8$ bits can represent $2's$ complement numbers in the range $-2^7$ to $2^7 -1$. Now the bias is added to aid in comparison purposes. In general to make the entire range non negative we can add a bias of $2^7$ to the exponent so that the range becomes $0$ to $2^8 -1$. But again the IEEE uses implicit normalization of mantissa as a result of which we need explicit representation of $0$ or $\pm \infty$. So biased exponent $E'=0$ or $255$ is reserved for this purpose.

So we have,

$$1 \leq E' \leq 254$$
$$\implies 1 \leq E+127 \leq 254$$
$$ ,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{(where E is the actual exponent)}$$
$$\implies -126 \leq E \leq 127$$

But had we used a bias of $128$ instead of $127$ then after reserving $E'=0 \text{ or } 255$

We would have got $$ -127 \leq E \leq 126$$

So my question is, Is there any technical reason for choosing $2^7-1$ instead of $2^7$ or it is just a convention followed by IEEE? Because using the bias of $128$ we could as well allow the required reservation for the special numbers, I see that the only difference comes in the range of the exponent, which shall become $[-127,126]$ instead of $[-126, 127]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jerome T. Coonen, "An Implementation Guide to a Proposed Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic," *Computer*, Vol. 13, No. 1, January 1980, pp. 68-79

provides the following rationale:

> Because of the care taken in the treatment of Underflows, the range of
> normalized numbers in *single*, *double*, and *quad* formats has been
> chosen to diminish slightly the risk of Overflow compared with the
> risk of Underflow. This was done by picking the exponent bias and
> alignment of the binary point in the significant digit field in such a
> way that the product of the largest and smallest positive normalized
> numbers is roughly 4 in each of the basic formats.

David Stevenson, "A Proposed Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic," *Computer*, Vol. 14, No. 3, March 1981, pp. 51-62

provides a somewhat different but related reasoning:

> For the 32-bit format, precision was deemed the most important
> criterion, hence the choice of radix 2 instead of octal or
> hexadecimal. Other characteristics include not representing the
> leading significand bit in normalized numbers, a minimally acceptable
> exponent range which uses eight bits, and an exponent bias which
> allows the reciprocal of all normalized numbers to be represented
> without overflow.

David Goldberg, "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", *ACM Computing Surveys*, Vol. 23, No. 1, March 1991, pp. 5-48

combines the above two explanations as follows:

> Referring to Table 1, single precision has *e*<sub>max</sub> = 127 and
> *e*<sub>min</sub>= -126. The reason for having |*e*<sub>min</sub>| < *e*<sub>max</sub> is so that the reciprocal of the smallest number (1/2<sup>*e*<sub>min</sub></sup>) will not overflow. Although it is
> true that the reciprocal of the largest number will underflow,
> underflow is usually less serious than overflow.

Comment: got a rough idea, so the main idea is to prevent overflow which is more frequent than underflow. Thanks a lot, I was totally unaware of the concept!!